# How to rewrite nginx to proxy?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

New to rewrites.  Running 2 services on my host:

```
  location /{
      #this works fine
      proxy_pass http://myMainServiceIp/;    
   }

   location /wordpress{
      #works but redirects to http://example.com/wp-admin/install.php
      #rather than http://example.com/blog/wp-admin/install.php
      proxy_pass http://wordpressServiceIp/;    
   }
```

How can I forward `/blog/*params*/*etc*/*etc*` to my wordpress service correctly?

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate but related issues. The `location` needs a trailing `/` so that `proxy_pass` can alias the URIs correctly.

```
location /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://wordpressServiceIp/;    
}
location = /blog {
    rewrite ^ /blog/ last;
}
```

I have added the second location block to handle the one special case.

The second issue is HOME and SITEURL needs to point to `http://example.com/blog/`. See [this document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for more.